# Why it's not possible to minify Latex code?

Tags: latex, minify, pdflatex, tex, overleaf

I'm writing Latex code in Overleaf and I was curious if it's possible to minify Latex code.

Maybe it isn't possible to fit all the code in just one line (like with Javascript) but it could be possible to have less LOCs in some ways.

Why? There isn't a specific reason, just curious.

I think it's not possible since I'm not finding any result in Google, but still want to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I think for the following specifications:

1. LaTeX code is designed to be readable and maintainable. It uses
   whitespace and comments to organize and explain the structure and
   content of a document. Removing these elements can make the code
   difficult to read and understand, especially for those who are not
   familiar with the document.
2. Minifying can potentially introduce errors or change the behavior of
   a LaTeX document, since some characters or sequences of characters
   may have special meanings in LaTeX. For example, removing a space
   between two words in a LaTeX command could change the command's
   meaning or result in an error.

Comment: it makes sense for some spaces.. but there's no specification here saying it's not possible to delete new lines for example...

Comment: @edoardottt New lines can have meaning for latex - you can remove them, but this can change the result.

Comment: yes I know, I wrote a lot of latex loc but still not all of them have an important meaning!